# Using YSLD functions and creating legends

Tags: geoserver, style, getlegendgraphic, ysld

My goal is to create legends, for `WMS` layers, which can be shown in a `JavaScript/OpenLayers 3` client.

Furthermore I found out, that GeoServer can generate legends via the `SLD` styles. This legends can be requested with a `GetLegendGraphic`-call.

I chose `YSLD` over `SLD` to write my styles because it is more readable and easier to write. Therefore my `YSLD` files look more or less like this:

```
name: simple-poly
title: 'A simple ysld style'
feature-styles: 
- rules:
  - name: Rule uses Categorize()
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: ${Categorize(foo,
          '#006600','73',
          '#00CC00','79',
          '#66FF66','85',
          '#996600','88',
          '#FFCC66','94',
          '#CCCCCC')}
```

Especially the `Categorize()` function saves a lot of lines. With these few lines my `WMS` layer gets rendered as expected.

The drawback with this approach seems to be that `GeoServer` can not handle the `Categorize()` function when creating a legend. Because the result of the `GetLegendGraphic`-call is an image with a gray square: [image: The created legend]

What is the best way to create a legend using `YSLD`, especially when `Categorize()` is used? Or is it simply not possible to use `Categorize()` and creating legends automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. On the one hand you seem to be saying that you know that Categorize() doesn't work in YSLD in GeoServer, and on the other you want to know how to use Categorize() with YSLD in Geoserver.

Comment: The YSLD style works for rendering the layer, but not for creating the legend for that layer. I added a sentence to clarify that the style works when rendering.

Comment: GetLegendGraphic is an (WMS +) SLD operation

Comment: So to get a proper legend I have to forget about YSLD and use SLD instead?

Comment: I don't know how the ysld plugin works with GeoServer and WMS operations; I guess that if what you have in YSLD is not possible in SLD, then your GetLegendGraphic won't work as expected.  The answer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228327/how-to-show-single-title-for-double-css-stroke-in-map-legend/) seems to confirm this thought.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look into into the generated `SLD` and saw that it also uses the `Categorize()` function. Therefore I tried to rewrite the `YSLD` without using `Categorize()`. With that `YSLD` the legend was created as expected.
This makes sense as that `YSLD` can be translated by `GeoServer` to a `SLD` file, which does not use functions. Therefore I also assume that other `YSLD` functions break the legend functionality.

*Results*

```
name: simple-poly
title: 'A simple ysld style'
feature-styles:
- name: 'A Rule'  
  rules:
  - name: below 73
    filter: ${foo < 73}
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: '#006600'
  - name: between 73 and 79
    filter: ${foo >= 73 AND foo < 79}
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: '#00CC00'       
  - name: between 79 and 85
    filter: ${foo >= 79 AND foo < 85}
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: '#66FF66'       
  - name: between 85 and 88
    filter: ${foo >= 85 AND foo < 88}
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: '#996600'
  - name: between 88 and 94
    filter: ${foo >= 88 AND foo < 94}
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: '#FFCC66'
  - name: below 94
    filter: ${foo > 94}
    scale: [min,max]
    symbolizers:  
    - polygon:
        fill-color: '#CCCCCC'
```

[image: The created legend]